# Update scroll position on resize of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, scrolltop, scroll-position

I'm currently using a combination of smooth scroll and IDs/anchor tags to scroll to content on my site. The code below is getting the ID of the next 'section' in the DOM, and adding it's ID as the 'view next section' href, so once it's clicked, it'll scroll to the top of that div. Then, it iterates through, updating the href with the next ID each time etc until the last section is seen and it scrolls back to the top. Pretty straightforward.

The only problem is that the 'sections' are fullscreen images, so as it's scrolling to the top of the next section, if you resize the browser, the top position of that section (where we scrolled to) has moved, and means the position is lost.

I've created a JSFiddle. You can see this happening after you click the arrow to visit the next section then resize the window: http://jsfiddle.net/WFQ9t/3/

I'm wanting to keep this top position fixed at all times so even if you resize the browser, the scroll position is updated to reflect this.

Thanks in advance,
R

```
var firstSectionID = $('body .each-section').eq(1).attr('id');
$('.next-section').attr('href', '#' + firstSectionID);

var i = 1;
$('.next-section').click(function() {

    var nextSectionID = $('body .each-section').eq(i).attr('id');
    i++;
    $('.next-section').attr('href', '#' + nextSectionID);

    var numberOfSections = $('body .each-section').length;
    var lastSectionID = $('body .each-section').eq(numberOfSections).attr('id');

    if ($('.next-section').attr('href') == '#' + lastSectionID ) { 
        $('.next-section').attr('href', '#introduction');
        i = 1;
    }

});
```

Comment: I would utilize a resize end plugin and simply trigger your existing smooth scrolling. Here is one possible plugin: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

Comment: I would actually just make a 1px div that scrolls with the page, then when window resize, always call that `.scrollTop()` of that div to get the real scroll position.

Comment: @ntgCleaner Thanks for the help. Can you provide an example? I understand the 1px div that scrolls with page, but how do I make the viewport stick to it on resize?

Comment: @rdck I am working on your fiddle now.  I'll see if I can come up with it soon.

Comment: @rdck what controls the movement of the divs?

Comment: @ntgCleaner This `$('.next-section').click(function()` click function. Or do you mean the slider? If so https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides

Comment: @rdck your images have been moved and it is difficult to work on the fiddle.  What I mean is, what piece of the canvas is moving around? I only see animations when images move left and right, but I do not see when they move up and down.  So far, I am working with changing the body `top` when resized, but your images are missing now.

Comment: @ntgCleaner Lemme just fix that real quick.

Comment: @ntgCleaner Here you go, http://jsfiddle.net/WFQ9t/3/ > I am using smooth scroll to move to each div with an ID corresponding to the `.next-section` href

Comment: @rdck Check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/WFQ9t/7/  It's pretty much working, but if you care, you'll have to place the `$('body')` reset inside of some animation.  Let me know if this works and I'll place it as an answer

Comment: @ntgCleaner Wow, this is great. This is very much appreciated. Quick q. Once you go through all the slides, and it goes back to the top, once you resize it starts freaking out again. The back to top is done by this code `if ($('.next-section').attr('href') == '#' + lastSectionID ) { 
   $('.next-section').attr('href', '#introduction');
   $('.ll-logo-small').addClass('first');
   i = 1;
  }` so maybe it's worth adding in `numSection = 1` here too?

Comment: That's correct,  I'll take another look today and post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Please check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WFQ9t/9/

The few things I did were:

1. Made some global variables to handle the screen number (which screen you're on and also the initial window height.  You will use this when the screen loads and also when you click on the `.next-session` arrow.

   ```
   var initWinHeight = $(window).height();
   var numSection = 0;
   ```
2. Then I tossed those variables into your `resizeContent()` function

   ```
   resizeContent(initWinHeight, numSection)
   ```

   so that it will work on load and resize
3. I made the `body` move around where it needs to, to accomodate for the movement of the divs (I still don't understand what divs are moving when the regular animation happens).

   ```
   $('body').css({
       top: (((windowHeight - initWinHeight)*numSection)*-1) + "px"
   });
   ```
4. Then in your click function, I add 1 to the section number, reset the initial window height and then also reset the `body` to `top:0`.  The normal animation you have already puts the next section at the top of the page.

   ```
   numSection++;
   initWinHeight = $(window).height();
   $('body').css({top:"0px"}, 1000);
   ```
5. Finally, I reset the `numSections` counter when you reach the last page (You might have to make this 0 instead of 1)

   ```
   numSection = 0;
   ```

The fiddle has all of this in the correct places, these are just the steps I took to change the code.

Comment: Many thanks! Looking at the jsFiddle, once you scroll through once and go back to top, once you resize, it still seems to lose it's top? Unless the jsFiddle link is wrong?

Comment: @rdck Edited the fiddle, changed the `numSection` to equal zero when the screens reset.  looks like it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that i found, but I dont use anchor links at this point, i use classes

Here is my HTML code:

```
<section class="section">
    Section 1
</section>

<section class="section">
    Section 2
</section>

<section class="section">
    Section 3
</section>

<section class="section">
    Section 4
</section>
```

And here is my jQuery/Javascript code, 
I actually used a preety simple way:

```
    $('.section').first().addClass('active');

/* handle the mousewheel event together with 
 DOMMouseScroll to work on cross browser */
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();//prevent the default mousewheel scrolling
    var active = $('.section.active');
    //get the delta to determine the mousewheel scrol UP and DOWN
    var delta = e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;

    //if the delta value is negative, the user is scrolling down
    if (delta < 0) {
        next = active.next();
        //check if the next section exist and animate the anchoring
        if (next.hasClass('section')) {
            var timer = setTimeout(function () {
                $('body, html').animate({
                    scrollTop: next.offset().top
                }, 800);

                next.addClass('active')
                    .siblings().removeClass('active');

                clearTimeout(timer);
            }, 200);
        }

    } else {
        prev = active.prev();

        if (prev.length) {
            var timer = setTimeout(function () {
                $('body, html').animate({
                    scrollTop: prev.offset().top
                }, 800);

                prev.addClass('active')
                    .siblings().removeClass('active');

                clearTimeout(timer);
            }, 200);
        }

    }
});


/*THE SIMPLE SOLUTION*/
$(window).resize(function(){
    var active = $('.section.active')

     $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: active.offset().top
    }, 10);
});
```